# Is it possible to assign a type to a function AND a function definition in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this use case:

Angular has a [TrackByFunction](https://angular.io/api/core/TrackByFunction) interface for public component functions.

I would like to do say "this function is a `TrackByFunction` directly on the component. Right now I am doing this:

```
  public readonly myObjectTrackingFn: TrackByFunction<MyObject> = (
    _: number,
    myObject: MyObject
  ): MyAlias => {
    return myObject.myDetail.alias;
  }
```

but some of my tooling (autoprefixers and lint libraries) have problems recognizing what are they.

I would like to write something like

```
<TrackByFunction> public myObjectTrackingFn(_: number, myObject: MyObject): MyAlias {
    return myObject.myDetail.alias;
  }
```

is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is correct, but maybe:

```
function myObjectTrackingFn(
  _: number,
  myObject: MyObject
): TrackByFunction<MyObject> {
  return (): MyAlias => myObject.alias;
}
```

Or maybe:

```
function myObjectTrackingFn(
  _: number,
  myObject: MyObject
) : TrackByFunction<MyObject>{
  return ((): MyAlias => {
    return myObject.alias;
  })();
}
```

Let me know if you find a way!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the second one using `MyAlias` as return instead of `TrackByFunction` seems to work but then the `TrackByFunction` info is missing. Also, in general in that way the function input parameters are not assure to be the one require by `TrackByFunction`